# How to use the fill option in ggplot2 by ascending order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

The data below represents the percentage of education (3 levels: 1 Low, 2 Mid, 3 High) in three different countries. I use the following code to plot them:

```
ggplot(df, aes(education)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(weight = percentage)) +
  facet_wrap(~country, ncol=3)
```

However, the bars are next to each other. I try to use the option `fill` as in the examples, but it is not working out for some strange reason. My aim is to fill one bar for each country whereby it includes the % of the three different levels of education. I would also like to rank the countries in the graph in the order based on education level 1. The lowest `percentage` in category 1 of `education` is the first bar on the left in the graph - going gradually to the highest `percentage` of category 1 in the education variable. Could someone guide me please?

```
country percentage  education
1         15           1
1         65           2
1         20           3
2         20           1
2          8           2
2         42           3
3         21           1
3         59           2
3         21           3

structure(list(country = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3), format.stata = "%9.0g"), percentage = structure(c(15, 65, 
20, 20, 28, 42, 21, 59, 21), format.stata = "%9.0g"), education = structure(c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you mean by "highest share of education".
Do you mean any type of education? Then it would be country 3 with 101 % of education.
Or do you mean highest share of high education? Then it would be country 1 with 65 % of level 3 education.

Please clarify.

You could have a look at the rank function (?rank), and make a new column using something like this: rank(df$percentage[which(test$education==3)])

(I would add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet).

Answer (score 2):

Use geom_col instead of geom_bar and set country as factor.

```
df$country <- as.factor(df$country)

ggplot(df, aes(x=education, y=percentage)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=country))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, my aim was to put country as x and education as fill. But feom_col worked as followed: ggplot(df, aes(x=country, y=percentage)) + geom_col(aes(fill=education))

But how can i rank the countries with the one of the highest share of education to the one of lowest?